# Need help assigning returned PHP data to Angular 2 object array

Tags: php, angular

I'm not sure how to use the data returned from my PHP code inside my angular class. I would like to be able to use my shelf component to take the data returned from the backend and create an array of Book. I'm receiving the data from PHP fine, I can see it returned when i check the headers. I'm just not familiar with Angular enough to know how to assign the returned data to the array of type Book.

Book interface

```
export interface Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    rating: number;
}
```

Shelf component (where I want to parse the data and use each as a Book)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../book';
import { BooksService } from '../books.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shelf',
  templateUrl: './shelf.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shelf.component.sass']
})
export class ShelfComponent implements OnInit {

  books: Book[] = [];

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBooks();
  }

  getBooks(): void {
    this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe( response => {
      console.log("success: " + response);
    }, 
    err => {
      console.log("error: " + err);
    });
  }
}
```

Books service (where i'm sending the request for the data to be used as Book(s) )

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from './book';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BooksService {

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
      return this.http.post<Book[]>("http://localhost/Projects/index.php", this.httpOptions )
      .pipe(map(response => response ));
  }
}
```

PHP code

```
$books[] = [ 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'test', 'rating' => '5'];
$books[] = [ 'id' => '2', 'title' => 'test2', 'rating' => '6'];

echo json_encode($books);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it should be as easy as assigning the value from the http request to the instance-variable of the

```
getBooks(): void {
  this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe( response => {
    this.books = response;
  }, 
  err => {
    console.log("error: " + err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API call format is wrong.

Think your API method type is GET. In that case you should be using http.get() in your angular service.

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>("http://localhost/Projects/index.php", this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(map(
              response => response
          ));
}
```

If your API method is POST then the second parameter in your angular service need to be the data you need to send to the api & the third options is httpOptions.

Read more here - https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    const dataToPost = 100; <-- Say a book id
    return this.http.post<Book[]>("http://localhost/Projects/index.php", 
        dataToPost, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(map(
              response => response
          ));
}
```

Once you get the response in the subscribe in the component you can simply assign it to the books variable.

```
getBooks(): void {
  this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe( response => {
    this.books = response;
  }, 
  err => {
     console.log("error: " + err);
  });
}
```